# JavaScript validation on slow client

Tags: javascript, arrays, client-side-validation

I'm assuming this is client or network issue, either way, here's the problem.

I'm using a text input (`#id_barcode`) to catch codes from a barcode scanner, since the scanner automatically adds an `[Enter]` I'm using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var scannedCodes = []; // No duplicates allowed!
    var re_code = /^B([A-Z]{2}\d{2})(\d{11})$/;
    re_code.compile(re_code);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#id_barcode").keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                processCode();
            }
        });
    });

    function processCode() {
        var text = $("#id_barcode").val().toUpperCase();
        $("#id_barcode").val(""); // Reset input
        if (text.match(re_code)) {
            var code = text.match(re_code)[0];
            if (scannedCodes.indexOf(code) != -1) {
                showError("Duplicated code: " + code);
            } else {
                scannedCodes.push(code);
                // More code here including an AJAX call for extra validation 
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

So if the code it's already in the array, the error message will be shown, but this is not happening in some cases. I ran a simple test in which I paste one random code, then press enter and repeat very quickly simulating the barcode scanner and this is what is happening:

[image]

It's not validating:

```
console.log(scannedCodes);
["BSG2410100141820", "BSG2410100141820", "BSG2410100141820"]
```

If I wait for another second and enter the same code, it validates. How can I overcome this?

Comment: I don't see any code that defines `text` (in `text.match`), nor do I see any code that adds the code to `scannedCodes`. If this happens in your AJAX call, then obviously you'll have latency problems. Add the code to the list of scanned codes *before* sending the AJAX call.

Comment: Did you check if the scanner is triggering enter before entering the codes? Your scenario would happen in that case.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol sorry, updated my question. The AJAX call is for something else

Comment: @LucasRodrigues yes. But the thing is that I did this manually simulating the scanner, pasting and hitting enter quickly

Comment: @CésarBustíos Can you create a running example?